# Are there any clues missing from this Geometry problem?

Tags: geometry

Let me start off with an apology for the terminology I'll use because English is not my main language nor the language we do math at College. I'll try my best to translate this problem from its original language, but feel free to correct me if there are any wrong terms in it. With that being said, here's the problem:

> Find the abscissa of point A with ordinate -2, located on the perpendicular line of the line passing through the points M(-2; 1) and N(-1; 2).

I've read this a hundred times but it still feels like there's something missing. Is it possible to solve this problem with this much information? Thanks in advance

Comment: The problem is not solvable with the current information.  Maybe instead of "perpendicular line" the problem meant "perpendicular bisector"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’m going to assume that the question means “perpendicular bisector” as a comment pointed out.  Find the equation of the line connecting points M and N. $$y=mx+b$$
$$1=m(-2) +b$$
$$2=m(-1)+b$$
2 equations, 2 unknowns.  Solve for m and b
$$-1=-m$$
$$m=1$$
$$1=-2+b$$
$$b=3$$
$$y=1x+3$$
This is the equation of the line connecting points M and N.

---

Now find the equation of the perpendicular bisector.  The slope of this line is the negative reciprocal of the slope of the line connecting points M and N $(m=-1)$.  So now we solve for b using the knowledge that the lines intersect halfway between x=-2 and x=-1.
$$y=-x+b$$
$$1.5=-(-1.5)+b$$
$$b=0$$
$$y=-x$$
This is the equation of the perpendicular bisector.
We know the y-coordinate of Point A is -2 and we solve for the x-coordinate using our new equation $y=-x$.  So we get $$-2=-x$$ $$x=2$$  So the abscissa of Point A is 2.